# Given input expressions, extract the base and make it as a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

Given input expressions, I want to extract the function and again extract its element.

For example, given my input

```
 f= b1 g[1, {a1,a2,a3}] + b2 g[1,{a11,a22,a33}] + b3 g[1,{a111,a222,a333}]
```

First I want to extract as follows :  $\{ \{a1,a2,a3\},\{a11,a22,a33\}, \{a111,a222,a333\} \}$

Since b1,b2,b3 are arbitrary I don't want to use

```
 coefficient[f,b1]
```

Any ideas or comments?

Comment: Just use `Cases[f, {__}, {3}]`

Comment: Or, `Cases[f, _List, All]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Cases[f, Times[b_. ,  g[k__]] :> {b, Last@k}, 1] // Transpose
```

> {{b1, b2, b3}, {{a1, a2, a3}, {a11, a22, a33}, {a111, a222, a333}}}